# Domain Modelling in Grakn - what's best for automated reasoning?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm thinking through a domain model, if I want to get the most out of Grakn's reasoner is it better to have more relations or more subtypes?

What should I be thinking about when considering various ways of modelling in Grakn?

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about how to model your domain in Grakn, we suggest focusing on how specific concepts behave in order to decide if you should be using a relation or a subtype.

So you subtype if you think the subtype is really a valid subtype, or use a relation if you think that a role is a better description of the behaviour of that type.

For example, consider person and teacher.

You could subtype `teacher` from `person`, but then what happens when a `person` is both a `teacher` and a `student`? In this case `person` should *play the roles* `teacher` and `student` in a relation instead of using inheritance (subtyping).